# Empty div is showing up with ruby .each enumerable on HTML.erb page.

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, each, enumerable

I can't seem to figure out why my ruby **.each** enumerable is churning out an empty div if my array of objects is empty, or adding an empty div at the bottom if there is one object in my **@posts** variable.

Here is my index.html.erb page:

```
<div id="post_feed">
<%if @posts.any?%>
  <%@posts.each do |p|%>
    <div class="post_text_box">
      <%=p.body%>
    </div>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
</div>
```

Post Controller:

```
def index
    @posts = current_user.posts
    @new_post = current_user.posts.new 
  end
```

CSS:

```
#post_feed{
  margin-right:auto; 
  margin-left:auto; 
  width:400px; 
}

.post_text_box{
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

rails console shows 1 item.

```
irb(main):014:0> Post.count
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts"
=> 1
```

[Here is an image of the empty div.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNfwN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it hasn't been saved yet, Rails is considering the `@new_post` to be part of `current_user.posts`, so  you have a blank post at the end of your `@posts` list.

It doesn't turn up in the database query because it hasn't been saved.

Depending on what you need to do, you could make `@new_post` just an empty post (`@new_post = Post.new`) and assign the user when saving.

Or in your `each` loop you you can check to see if the post has a body before creating the `div` if you can rely on that check to give you the results you want:

```
<div id="post_feed">
  <%@posts.each do |p|%>
    <% if p.body %>
       <div class="post_text_box">
         <%=p.body%>
        </div>
     <%end%>
   <%end%>
 </div>
```

You don't need the `if @posts.any?` check as it will always evaluate to `true` because of the new post created with `@new_post = current_user.posts.new`.

And generally in ruby, you won't need to check if an array is empty before running an `each` loop because the `each` loop won't do anything (or throw an error) with an empty array.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph.  Your way is a lot cleaner than the mess I concocted.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  In my controller, I am creating an new object but not saving it.  My .each iterator is recognizing it as an object in my @posts object array even though its not saved.

I fixed it by check if the record was new using the **new_record?** method.

```
<div id="post_feed">
<%if @posts.any?%>
  <%@posts.each do |p|%>
   <%if ! p.new_record?%>
    <div class="post_text_box">
      <%=p.body%>
    </div>
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
</div>
```